# Refreshing frame page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following two frames frame 1 with name="top" and frame 2 with name "main". Now in main there is a button called add number, which brings up a normal browser popup, in this popup I have a form that needs to be filled in and then I click submit on this form and then the main frame should reload, the form processing happens within the popup page and then after processing the main frame should refresh. The following code does not work, Am I doing something wrong?

```
window.opener.main.reload();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
parent.opener.location.reload();
```